# jboss database connection timeout when idle in oracle

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jboss, firewall, connection-timeout

I have java apps deployed on Jboss eap 6.3 in redhat 6 connected to oracle 11g.
I am using jdbc connection like this :

```xml
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/myjdbc" pool-name="myConfigDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="false" statistics-enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(enable=broken)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MYSERVICENAME)))</connection-url>
    <connection-property name="oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT">10000</connection-property>
    <driver>oracle</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>myusername</user-name>
        <password>mypassword</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</check-valid-connection-sql>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
        <background-validation-millis>60000</background-validation-millis>
        <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
        <blocking-timeout-millis>5000</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
    </timeout>
</datasource>
```

If that app idle in several hours and we tried to query int database, database IO connection timeout occur.

In my investigation I assume that network firewall blocked this connection if no traffic inside.
My question is how to deal with network firewall? Is there any parameter to add inside jndi connection in jboss xml configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @squallbayu not 100% sure if this might help, and you've likely already solved the problem however according to our DBA's `enable=broken` only works if DCD `Dead Connection Detection` is enabled on the database server, our server(s) an Oracle ODA.  This PDF from Oracle [Dead Connection Detection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/oraclenetdcd-2179641.pdf) might help you or your DBAs get it setup and theres also an Oracle note `1641167.1` that describes it.

The **Executive Overview** is:

> Dead Connection Detection (DCD) is a feature of Oracle Net which helps in recovering resources allocated for a connection that is no longer usable.  DCD has been enhanced in Oracle Database 12c to reduce detection time drastically from about 15 minutes to as low as 2-3 minutes.  This paper [the PDF link] provides an overview of 12c and pre-12c DCD mechanisms, configuration details and benefits of the 12c mechanism

In short its basically setting SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME to something like 10 minutes in the database SQLNET.ORA file.