# Idle connections in JBoss pool

Tags: oracle, jboss, c3p0

We have a JBoss application where the database connections are managed via C3PO. Recently the DB node (Oracle DB) had gone down and ever since the restart of the DB we are seeing intermittent timeouts during the DB call. Ideally new connections should've been made after the DB node had come back up but looks like the connections were still persistent and had gone idle.

C3PO configurations I think could be responsible:
**hibernate.c3p0.timeout=300
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=1800**

Upon some research i read that the idle_test_period should not be higher than the c3p0.timeout. Does this hold good and if yes what's how do these values determine when a connection is idle and has to be removed from the pool?

Comment: I know this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203736/jboss-database-connection-timeout-when-idle-in-oracle/45887930#45887930) with my answer to someone else's similar issue isnt hibernate related but possibly it might help you out as you're also using Oracle DB and JBoss - we needed to make the same change on our servers.  If it helps, let me know and I'll add it as an answer

Comment: @JGlass Your link is about DCD, which is about the DB side configuration. In my case i believe the connections were closed from the DB but the Application still used these faulty connections. That's why i suspect c3p0 configuration could be the problem. Your link talks states DCD as a cause , which occurs when client goes down, mine occurred after the DB server went down, implying the source of problem could be on the client configuration side.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on your comment as we added as I work for a cable company, we have numerous maintenance's during the night at which points are internal network can become unstable.  One of our vendors applications runs on JBoss EAP 6 and has numerous connections from 4 nodes to an Oracle 12g ODA Database.  After some maintenance's, the nodes would begin throwing errors with regards to the database connections - adding the above to the Oracle TNS entries for the connections corrected the issue for us - but again, with regards to your comment - it could just be our environment.

Comment: To clarify a bit as well - this change is made on the database server and also on the client in the TNS entry, I cant find the email that went around on the exact change on the client but I can check the servers if you want - the infamous ["Tom"](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1784142376742) at Oracle also has a Q & A long thread on it, may help you out

Comment: @JGlass I have asked the DBAs to let me know if DCD has been implemented. Meanwhile we have done a restart of the application and has solved the issue, leading me to believe this has mostly to do with client configuration.

Comment: Glad to see the restart worked out!  DCD does seem like a good thing to utilize.  Have a great one!